# what does -Dfast mean in mvn command line?

Tags: java, maven

i got this comamnd to compile project.

mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfast  -Dmaven.compile.fork=true -Dscala-2.11

but i dont quite understand -Dfast mean,after search all the pages still got nothing related to this.

Anyone can help me?

searched document and github but no answer for this.

i wanna know the exactly meaning of this parameter.

my pom file
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml? Which plugins do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the POM, one sees that it activates a profile:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>fast</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
        <name>fast</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
```